# Error in clock_gettime in ctime

Tags: ctime

I have this function:

void Estatisticas::iniciarTempo() {

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &tempoInicial);
```

}

I'm trying to use clock_gettime by ctime, but I getting some errors:

"undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the clock_gettime/clock_getres manpage:

> Link with -lrt.

The symbol is defined in the POSIX Real Time library.  Add "-lrt" to your compilation line:

```
gcc -lrt -o myprog myprog.c
```